# SQL: How to select multiple values from one table as seperate columns

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I'm writing a C# WinForm Application, the data is displayed in a DataGridView.

Example of table

```
ITEMNO|VALUE|OPTFIELD
Item 1|A|LOCATION
Item 1|25|STOCKQTY
Item 2|B|LOCATION
Item 2|10|STOCKQTY
```

What I currently display in the DGV

```
PARTNUMBER | LOCATION
Item 1 | A
```

What I want to display

```
PARTNUMBER|LOCATION|STOCKQTY
Item 1 | A | 25
```

I was thinking of amending the Query as;

```
SELECT ITEMNO, VALUE, OPTFIELD, OPTFIELD AS STOCKQTY
FROM ICITEMO
WHERE ITEMNO = 'Item 1' and OPTFIELD LIKE 'LOCATION1' and OPTFIELD LIKE 'STOCKQTY'
```

But this returns no results

As the data is contained in one column, how do I display the separate values in separate columns, despite coming from one column?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, with case expressions in the select list.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason for designing your table that way, it's better to stick with a conventionally normalised design.  Your question is a good example of the difficulties you will experience if you go down this road. Google variations on  "SQL key value" or "entity attribute table" for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately the table design cannot change, it's a Sage 300 table. Having to work with what I've got. The current system just pulls through the part number and location, however the users require stock qty as well now.

Comment: In that case, if I had a lot of queries to write, I might consider creating temporary tables or views that pivot the data out into normal form first, then running queries against those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple pivot as below:

```
select * from #youritem
pivot (max(value) for optfield in ([LOCATION],[STOCKQTY])) p
```

Your output:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
| itemno | LOCATION | STOCKQTY |
+--------+----------+----------+
| Item 1 | A        |       25 |
| Item 2 | B        |       10 |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Your input table:

```
create table #youritem (itemno varchar(10), value varchar(5), optfield varchar(20))

insert into #youritem
(ITEMNO,VALUE, OPTFIELD ) VALUES
 ('Item 1','A ','LOCATION')
,('Item 1','25','STOCKQTY')
,('Item 2','B ','LOCATION')
,('Item 2','10','STOCKQTY')
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about pivots. Works perfectly